# Unable to get updated values in form textfields using innerHTML in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm binding for using innerHTML

```
    this.html = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(
          '<iframe width="100%" height="800" src="assets/template_forms/registration_form.html"></iframe>',
        );

<div [innerHtml]="html"></div>
```

the form is rendered like this

[image]

if i entered some test in input fiekd thennot getting updated value in form input value when accessed html variable.

Any solution Thanks

Comment: Why would you add the form element via iframe? I would suggest adding the inout directly to the template and do your data binding there. The "this.html" only includes the iframe itself, not the source that the iframe is loading.

Comment: @makkusu all forms are saved in assets folder that are like template so we need to load those forms in single angular component that's why using innerHTML but after submission i need updated values what user entered

Comment: Maybe you want to check angular components again. There's easier ways to include templates for certain components and I'd also say other ways are much more best practice. You're making it more comlicated than it has to be I think.